# Using the Chrome.socket API to connect to socket.io

Tags: sockets, google-chrome-extension, websocket, socket.io

I'm making a mobile chrome app (see: https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps for an explanation of what I'm talking about) that I plan to release onto the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com), and while it's been great so far, I can't seem to get my head around how I would use the [chrome.socket](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html) API to talk with [Socket.io](http://socket.io/).

The reason I'm not just using the Socket.io native commands is that I'm looking to support WebSocket on more than just the latest version on android (Androidn 4.4-KitKat supports the latest WebSocket spec out of the box, but every version before that does not), and by using the chrome.socket API you can get access to the patches that google have made behind the scenes to allow this (it also gives access to UDP, which might be something I'd like much later on).

TL;DR

How can I connect to a Socket.io server using the the chrome.socket API made available by the chrome-mobile-app framework (please note that it is functionally identical to the chrome extension one).

Thanks Girls and Guys!